# Edgy accuracy and loss plots in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I use tensorboard to visualize learning of my neural networks. Currently, I am working with datasets of such size, that equal, say 80%/20% split into training and development collections leaves me with the data that does not fit into memory during processing, so I have to use batches for development step.

When I do so, I end up with following shapes on the tensorboard charts:

[image: batched and unbatched accuracy]

Light-green line represents batched summary, while the dark green one represents unbatched development processing. I used datasets of same size and split for those two charts.

Here is the code, that is used to populate summaries

```
# accuracy definition in network
network.correct_predictions = tf.equal(predictions, tf.argmax(input_y, 1))
network.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")
network.loss = tf.reduce_mean(_losses)

# accuracy summary
acc_summary = tf.scalar_summary("accuracy", network.accuracy)
loss_summary = tf.scalar_summary("loss", network.loss)

# dev data summary writer
dev_summary_operation = tf.merge_summary([loss_summary, acc_summary])
dev_summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(dev_summary_dir, session.graph)

# dev step
def dev_step(x_batch, y_batch)
    feed_dict = {network.input_x: x_batch, network.input_y: y_batch}
    step, summaries, loss, accuracy = session.run([global_step, dev_summary_operation, network.loss, network.accuracy], feed_dict)
    dev_summary_writer.add_summary(summaries, step)
```

Same approach during training step gives normal lines (those, that are not edgy) since training is batched in both cases.
In both cases (batched or not) development summary gets updated once in 100 training batches.

Suggestions of reasons for such behaviour and possible fixes are more than welcome and highly appreciated.